# How to focus on HTML input with CSS?

Tags: html, css, focus

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<span id="span_pagination_text_input">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pagination_text_input" name="pagination_text_input"/>
     ...
</span>
```

And Following CSS:

```
span#span_pagination_text_input{
    position:relative;
}

span#span_pagination_text_input > input#pagination_text_input{
    left: -11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    width: 57px;
    z-index: 10;
    display:none;
    text-align:center
}
span#span_pagination_text_input:hover > input#pagination_text_input{
    display:block;
}
```

At this time when visitors hover on my `span`, I will show the `input` field which is hidden by default.

How I can focus on `input` children of `span` when I show that with CSS?

I know about jQuery but at this time I am looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: You can't do it in CSS.

Comment: you can use css like  input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: or use https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/glowing-blue-input-highlights/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `tabindex` which HTML5 allows in all elements now along with the `:focus`, to fake the `display:none` use `border:0`

```css
input {
  border: 0;
  width: 57px;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center
}
span:focus input {
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition: border .1s
}
input:focus {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span tabindex="1" id="span_pagination_text_input">
  Click me
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pagination_text_input" name="pagination_text_input" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible with only css. You can try javascript

```
document.getElementById("IdOfInput").focus();
```

:-)

Comment: I am looking for a solution which does not use from jQuery and Javascript

Comment: Then i don't think css is the solution